# Java: Method finds location not value of highest value of array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So I have a method that is supposed to find the highest value in my array.
Written as follows:

```
static public int findIndexOfMax(int[] intList, int countOfInts)
{
    int largest = intList[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < intList.length; i++)
    {
        if (intList[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = intList[i];
        }
    }
    return countOfInts;
}
```

My problem is that it doesn't print the VALUE it prints the LOCATION of the highest value

The code where it is output:

```
int indexLargestValue = findIndexOfMax( intList, countOfInts);
    System.out.println("\nReq #3a: The largest value in the array is at array index " + indexLargestValue );  
    System.out.println("Req #3b: The largest values in the array is " + intList[ indexLargestValue ] );
```

Where am I going wrong?

The highest value is 113.....

Output for proof:

```
The largest value in the array is at array index 12
```

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to show where you output that. Your output literally says "array index". Why do you expect a value instead?

Comment: It doesn't return the location of the highest value...

Comment: So you have to save the index of the largest value like `largestIndex = i;`

Comment: r u even using 'countOfInts'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are returning `countOfInts` instead of `largest`:

```
static public int findIndexOfMax(int[] intList, int countOfInts)
{
    int largest = intList[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < intList.length; i++)
    {
        if (intList[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = intList[i];
        }
    }
    return largest; // <<== Here
}
```

If this is what you need, rename `findIndexOfMax` to `findMax`.

If you need to find the location, change the body of the function as follows:

```
int largest = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < intList.length; i++)
{
    if (intList[i] > intList[largest])
    {
        largest = i;
    }
}
return largest;
```

Note: both versions need to check that the array has at least one value in it to avoid throwing an exception.

Comment: thanks....at least you're helpful.  I feel like beginner questions aren't tolerated on this website at all...

Comment: @WeekzSO I think the downvotes had to do with not seeing the complete information (i.e. the part about printing) before the edit. It is also my observation that the voting patterns change depending on the time of the day. I think your question is fine. Good luck with your project!

Comment: thanks...i hate the attitude on here...whats the point if you're not really going to help the people who really struggle